# Shade the area in a PDF plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I'm just curious if one can color/shade the area in a specific region on a PDF of some plot.

For instance:

[image]

lambda = 24. Let's say I wanted to shade the area P(x>= 24).

*Sorry for the sloppiness. The syntax doesn't seem to be the same as in previous sites I use.*

I already know how to compute that probability, but can it be shaded for visual convenience ?

```
 1-ppois(23,24) = .527
```

Comment: that doesn't look like a poisson distribution

Comment: regardless of the plot (It was data that was exponentially distributed but transformed to poisson), do you have any ideas? I realized I couldn't actually do this task because it is discrete. But I am guessing there is some way to shade between areas for continuous variables